# $_GET issue after url rewriting in PHP

Tags: php, url-rewriting

My original URL is `customers.php?id=3` and I get customer ID by writing `$_GET['id']`.

Now I wrote rewrite rules in htdocs and my URL is `customers/id/3`. I'm trying to get customer ID by `$_GET['id']`  which is not working. Can anyone please tell me what should I do to get ID?

My URL Rewrite is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customers/([^/]*)$ /customers.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you show us your `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Wouldn't the first example be `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: I think you're wanting `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: How are you rewriting the URL?  Can you show us your `.htaccess` (or wherever you put the lines)?  You could try using [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to keep the query string after the redirect.  Also, I think you mean `$_GET['id']` in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is wrong; you are capturing everything after the `customers/` section until the first forward slash and you are not allowing anything after that.

In you example the rule would not even trigger as your url has a forward slash and characters after it.

You should change:

```
RewriteRule ^customers/([^/]*)$ /customers.php?id=$1 [L]
```

to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^customers/id/(\d+).*$ /customers.php?id=$1 [L]
                               ^^ Allow for extra stuff after the id so you could add the name of your customer or something like that
                          ^^^^^ Require at least one digit and only digits
```

You could also get rid of the ID if you wanted to so that the number would come directly after `customer/` but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
customers.php?id=3
```

Use:

```
$_GET['id']
```

not $_GET['customers'].

If you want to get "customers", use: `customers.php?customers=3`

Your rewrite will be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^customers/id/([0-9]+)$ customers.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: ya sorry by mistake i write customer, now I update my question

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to parse urls of that style (customer/id/123):

```
$aUrlPieces = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($aUrlPieces);
```

The last 3 elements in the array will be "customer", "id" and "123".

You can go one step further and define action methods in your application that would take corresponding amount of parameters, that way your urls will be syntax checked by PHP.

In this case, action method "customer" would take 2 parameters `$identifier_type` and `$identifier_value`.

That way if you accidentally mistype "customers/" instead of "customer/" you will get "Method not defined" exception.

Answer (score 0):

change your rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /customers.php?id=$1 [L]
```